# If $(p\implies (q \implies r)$ and $q \implies r$ then does $r \implies q$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

The question is like this

The original Question:

> By defining appropriate propositions, show that the following inference is valid. You will lose
>   points if you do not give reasons for every statement you infer.
>
> • If the prime interest rate goes up, then it is sufficient that unemployment goes down for prices to rise.
>
> • However, unemployment goes down only if the prime interest rate goes up.
>
> • Therefore, if prices do not go up, then unemployment does not go down.

-if P then Q for R (for example)

> If the prime interest rate goes up, then it is sufficient that unemployment goes down for prices to rise

-However, Q if P

-Therefore, if $\neg R$ then  $\neg Q$

So far, I have deduced

first statement
$$p\implies(q\implies r)$$

second statement

$$p\implies q$$

and so it modus ponens can be used to deduce

$$q\implies r$$ $$q$$ $$\therefore r$$

which proves that

$$r\implies  q$$

inturn proving the hypothesis

$$\neg r\implies \neg q$$

is this correct or have I gone horribly wrong at some point?

Comment: What does "for" mean in if P then Q for R? Maybe its a typo and should be if P then Q or R.

Comment: Also one can't go from $r \implies q$ to $\lnot r \implies \lnot q.$

Comment: would it be it's contra-positive??? of would it be like 

$q\implies r$

Contrapositive:

$r\implies q$

Comment: @coffeemath I did provide an example although the interest now piques me that if we are given that $q\implies r$ then do we have no need for the second statement as the contrapostive of the $q\implies r$ proves the hypothesis?

Comment: Agent-- To your first above, contrapositive means switch the sides and negate each. For the second I can't see why one wants to prove one of the hypotheses anyway.

Comment: @coffeemath, We are asked to prove the therefore statement, however I was stuck as to how I would prove the therefore statement. I know it is true because I can interpret and understand but we have to prove it using inferences and is been confusing me lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the symbolization correct.  Yes, the statement

> If the prime interest rate goes up, then it is sufficient that unemployment goes down for prices to rise

Does indeed translate to $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$, assuming you are using:

$P$: Prime interest rate goes up

$Q$: Unemployment goes down

$R$: Prices rise

However, with this, the statement

> However, unemployment goes down only if the prime interest rate goes up.

translates to $Q \rightarrow P$, rather than $P \rightarrow Q$

You seem to be unfamiliar with the difference between '$P$ if $Q$' and '$P$ only if $Q$', so here is example.

We know that someone can be a bachelor only if they are unmarried.  However, not everyone who is unmarried is a bachelor. Being unmarried is therefore not a *sufficient* condition for being a bachelor, but it is one of several *necessary* conditions for being a bachelor, for one also has to be male, and of adult age.  So, 'bachelor only if unmarried' does *not* translate into $Unmarried \rightarrow Bachelor$.  However, it *does* translate into $Bachelor \rightarrow Unmarried$, exactly because being unmarried is a necessary condition for being a bachelor!

In general, '$P$ only if $Q$' translates to $P \rightarrow Q$, which is the converse of '$P$ if $Q$'

With the corrected symbolization, you should be able to prove the desired result.

Comment: so then how would you suggest I prove the therefore statement as I cannot get q implies r to be true(which is needed to say that the contrapositive is true)

Comment: @AgentSmith You can't!  You can't prove something that's not valid (unless you use inference rules that are not valid themselves, but you certainly don't want to do that) ... so, are you sure you have the symbolization all correct?  Can you maybe post some more details of the original question?

Comment: I have linked the original question on the post if you can check thanks you!

Comment: @AgentSmith Ah!  OK, then I see the mistake. A statement of the form ' A only if B' is different from 'A if B'. Whereas 'A if B'  gets translated as $B \rightarrow A$, 'A only if B' gets translated as $A \rightarrow B$

Comment: is there a reason as to why A only if B would reciprocate it?? because wouldn't it mean the same if B then A? As A would be True if B is true so basically $B\implies A$ ?? or did I get it wrong??

Comment: Also @Bram28 if that is true then would it be like 
$q\implies (q\implies r)$ as $p\implies (q\implies r)$ and $q\implies p$

and from that can I conclude that 
$q\implies r$ is true, therefore the contrapositive is true, hence $\neg r\implies \neg q$

Comment: @AgentSmith I just added an explanation to my Answer

Comment: That explained me a lot thanks.

 one last clarification if you can,

would $q\implies(q\implies r)$ be the same as $q\implies r$

Comment: @AgentSmith they are equivalent, yes, ... but I am not sure if you want to use that in a formal proof, since there is probably no inference rule in the system you are taught that can do that equivalence in one step. So just do this: assume Q ... that gives you P .. and that gives you Q -> R. ANd therefore you have R. So, you have Q ->R. And therefore ~R -> ~Q

Comment: that was a great hint that cleared everything, so you are saying that
$$q\implies p\implies (q\implies r)$$ is basically $$q\implies r$$ and therefore $\neg R\implies \neg Q$ Through contrapositive.

Comment: @AgentSmith not quite, because you need the $P$ ... but you get that one from $Q$ and $Q \rightarrow P$

Comment: so you mean we use the exportaion law? like $q\implies (q\implies r)$ would be $(q \land q)\implies r$ which is $q\implies r$ and since that is true so is contrapositive proving it is right!

Comment: @AgentSmith Yes, using Exporation and Idempotence you can indeed go from $Q \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$ to $Q \rightarrow R$ ... but you donlt have $Q \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$. All you have is $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$ and $Q \rightarrow P$.  But between those two premises, you can do a conditional proof to show $Q \rightarrow R$

Comment: But can't I use hypothetical Syllogism to get $Q\implies (Q\implies P)$ from  $P\implies (Q\implies P)$ and $Q\implies P$ ?? and which would then prove it?

Although sorry I have troubled you a lot but I still do not understand as to what do you mean by conditional proof?

Comment: @AgentSmith Ah, yes, you're absolutely right: hypothetical syllogism will work just fine!  Well, that's it then! :)

Comment: thanks a lot you helped a lot!!!!!!!